# Override load-styles.php with admin screen css

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to modify css.

[image]

I tried to modify the css with below code but does seems to work. if i try to change the color it works.

```
 #poststuff #post-body.columns-2 {
    margin-right: 300px;
    display:flex important;
    flex-direction:column !important;
}
```

It seems to work in if i modify directly form the chrome developer.

```
function wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script( $hook ) {
    if ( 'toplevel_page_kita-general-settings' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myscript.js', array(), '1.0' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'kita_options_page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/kita-admin.css' );


}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_selectively_enqueue_admin_script' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its just that one style you want to edit, you could try...

```
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_styles');

function admin_styles() {
    echo '<style>
        #poststuff #post-body.columns-2 {
            margin-right: 300px;
            dispay:flex important;
            flex-direction:column !important;
        }
    </style>';
}
```

Or add a separate stylesheet with something like this...

```
add_action('admin_head', 'admin_styles');

function admin_styles() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />';
}
```

Comment: hi,thanks..tried but it is not working. its still loads from load-styles.php .

Comment: What exactly are you trying to override?  Also, how are you creating this theme options page?

Comment: its not actually overriding ...i tried to move the publish button to bottom..these were the newly added codes:dispay:flex important;flex-direction:column !important;

Comment: Well display is spelled wrong and you are missing the ! before important

Comment: oh yes . above code works . Thanks How can i target the specific page :  'toplevel_page_kita-general-settings'

Comment: is that on the body tag?  just add .toplevel_page_kita-general-settings before your selector.  For example .toplevel_page_kita-general-settings #poststuff #post-body.columns-2 { ... }

Answer (score -1):

My Best Way using `wp_enqueue_style` you can use random `$version` to avoid cache browser.

```php
function admin_styles() { 
    $ver = rand();
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'adminStyle', 
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin.css',
        [],
        $ver
    );
}
```